# geting each element of a textfile until ':' and store on struct variable

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I need help :/

On textfile, I have something like this:
MyName:  15  3

and I want to read each element until ':' and store it in variable name of the struct, and read the next elements and store 15 and 3 in another variables.

```
typedef struct STRUCT_PLAYER{char name[20];
                        int sucess;
                        int numQuest;
                        int wrongs;} PLAYER;


int readTop(PLAYER playTop[]){
    char *classify = "classificacao.txt";
    FILE *fl;
    fl = fopen(classify, "r");

    char c;
    int n=0;

    if(cl==NULL){
        printf("Error reading the file %s\n", classify);
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        while(c!=EOF){
            while(c!=':'){
                c=getc(fl);
                if(c!=':') playTop[n].name=c;
            }
            if(c==':')fscanf(fl, "  %d  %d\n", &playTop[n].numQuest, &playTop[n].wrongs);

            n++;

        }

    }
return n;
```

this is my code, but it appears me an error, on this line

*if(c!=':') playerTOP[n].nome=c;*

error: assignment to expression with array type

but I don't understand what it is

Comment: while(c!=EOF) .... nope, not with c of char type.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  it is missing the needed `#include` statements, it is missing a `main()` function, the function: `readTop()` is missing the final closing brace '}'.   Please post a [mcve]

Comment: regarding: `if(cl==NULL){`.  the variable `cl` is not defined in the posted code.  Exactly what is being checked?

Comment: regarding: `fl = fopen(classify, "r");`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()` to output the enclosed text and the reason the system thinks the operation failed to `stderr`.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) use meaningful variable names.  names like: `c`, `n`, `cl`, `fl` are meaningless, even in the current context.  (note: a file pointer, such as returned from `fopen()` is usually named: `fp`, with slight additions if there is more than one file

Comment: the function: `getc()` is 'usually' implemented as a macro that invokes `fgetc()`.  Suggest directly using `fgetc()`

Comment: Note the `getc()` (fgetc())  returns an `int`, not a `char` and `':'` is a `int`, not a `char`

Comment: the function signature should include a parameter that contains the number of entries in the array: `playTop[]` so the code can check that the array is not being overrun.

Comment: the variable `c` is not initialized, so will contain what ever trash is on the stack at its' location.  this could happen to be `EOF`  Strongly suggest initializing `c`, perhaps to '0'

Comment: the field of the struct: `name[]` can hold a string of 19 characters plus a NUL terminator byte.  1) there is no check to assure that field is not being overrun.  2) the string is not being NUL terminated

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: thank you @user3629249 I will analyze and try to understand each one of your comments. I didn't put the `#include` and the `main()` because I only have doubts in the creation of this function, but now I can see that I should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is `char`, `playTop->name` is a `char[]`, so your are assigning incompatible types. Also

> *coderredoc [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129407/1480131)*
>
> Array name is not a modifiable lvalue

When you initialize your structure do:

```
int n=0;
playTop[n].name[0] = 0;

...

while(c!=':'){
    char cs[] = { getc(fl), 0 };
    if(c!=':')
        strcat(playTop[n].name, cs);
}
```

With this `cs` is a C-String containing one letter only and `strcat` appends
the string to `playTop[n].name`, thus saving the name

---

**EDIT**

> *Ricardo's comment*
>
> thank you. but I din't understant why you put a zero on `char cs[] = { getc(fl), 0}`

That is what I was talking about in the comment. In C a string **must** be
`'\0'`-terminated.

A C-String is a sequence of bytes. This sequence **must** end with the value 0.
Every value in the sequence represents a character based on the
[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding, for example the
character `'a'` is 97, `'b'` is 98, etc. The character `'\0'` has
the value 0 and it's the character that determines the end of the string.
That's why you hear a lot that C-Strings are '\0'-terminated.

In C you use an array of chars (`char string[]`, `char string[SOME VALUE]`) to
save a string. For a string of length *n*, you need an array of dimension *n+1*, because
you also need one space for the terminating `'\0'` character.

When dealing with strings, you always have to think about the proper type,
whether your are using an array or a pointer. A pointer
to char doesn't necessarily mean that you are dealing with a C-String!

Let's take a look at

```
char str1[] = "Hallo";
char str2[] = { 'H', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };
```

Both declarations do the same thing, they initialized the arrays `str1` and
`str2` with 6 elements. `str1[5]` and `str2[5]` will be the same: 0 (or `'\0'`
in its `char` notation).

A string literal is the text that is wrapped in quotes, `"Hello"` is a string
literal. Somewhere in the memory of the process the linker puts the sequence
`'H', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0` in memory, usually read-only memory (note the 0
at the end). Even though you don't write the `'\0'` explicitly, it will have
one.

The '`\0`' at the end of the sequence of `char`s is what makes the sequence a
C-String, not the type of the variable. If there is no '`\0`' at the end, it is not a C-String.

```
char cs[] = { getc(fl), 0};
```

is a shorthand of

```
char cs[2];
cs[0] = getc(fl);
cs[1] = '\0';
```

By doing the last assignments, I ensure that `cs` holds a C-String. Most
functions defined in `string.h` (standard library) expect C-Strings, so they
must be `'\0'`-terminated.

> *man strcat*
>
> ```
>   #include <string.h>
>
>   char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string,
>   overwriting the terminating null byte (`'\0'`) at the end of `dest`, and
>   then adds a terminating null byte.

From the description you'll see that both `dest` and `src` must be strings,
thus `'\0'`-terminated. That's why I said you should initialize
`playTop->name[0]` with 0, so that is will be a valid (and empty) string. Only
then I can use `strcat`.

Luckily there are many ways to archive the same results. If you don't want to
use `strcat` you could do it also this way:

```
int name_idx = 0;
while(c!=EOF){
    while(c!=':'){
        c=getc(fl);
        if(c!=':') playTop[n].name[name_idx++]=c;
    }
    if(c == ':')
    {
        // make sure that playTop[n].name is a c-string
        playTop[n].name[name_idx] = 0;
        fscanf(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

One last thing:

It's not bad using an array for saving strings, the problem is that the
maximum length of the string is `dimension or array - 1`. In your case the
name *must* not be longer than 19 characters, otherwise you will have a buffer
overflow and you are going to write over memory that is not allocated for the
name, you will have undefined behaviour and anything could happen.

When you know that the max. length of your string won't pass certain value
(let's say 15), then it's fine to use `char name[20]`. If there's no guarantee
of a max. length, then you have to dynamically allocate memory for it using
`malloc`/`realloc` (and later you would have to free that memory).

Also, a better way to parse your line would be to use `fgets` to get the while
line and then parse it:

```
typedef struct STRUCT_PLAYER{char *name;
                        int sucess;
                        int numQuest;
                        int wrongs;} PLAYER;


int readTop(PLAYER playTop[]){
    ...
    char line[1024];
    fgets(line, sizeof line, fl);

    int colon_index = strchr(line, ':');

    // color_index is the index where : is in the line,
    // the length of the name is colon_index - 1
    // because you have to save \0 as well, you need to
    // allocate one more space for the c-string
    //   name length  + 1 ==> (colon_index - 1) + 1
    // which equeals to colon_index
    playTop[n].name = malloc(colon_index);

    // copy the name from line into name. strncpy
    // copies at most `colon_index - 1` characters, if
    // \0 is not among them, it won't be appended at the end
    // you have to do that
    strncpy(playTop[n].name, line, colon_index - 1);

    // making sure that name becomes a c-string
    playTop[n].name[colon_index] = 0;

    // sscanf is like fscan, only it takes the content from
    // a string and not from a FILE object.
    // line + colon_index + 1 ensures that sscanf reads only
    // after the colon
    sscanf(line + colon_index + 1, "...", ...);
}
```

Doing it this way, you ensure that the name can have any length. **Note** that
all these functions may fail: for example `malloc` might return `NULL` if
there is not enough memory, `strchr` might return `NULL` if a colon is not
found in the line (the line has a wrong format or is empty). The line itself could be
longer than 1024 bytes. For sake of simplicity I've omitted all those checks.

If you've understood my code, then you could make it better by checking for
the errors mentioned above. Read carefully the documentation of the functions
used here.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I new at C and this was my mistake. name is a string, and I and trying to equal the string to the char element.  With this I think i can solve. Thank you

Comment: Bear in mind, that just because you have a `char*` or a `char[]`, you don't necessarily have a string! A C-String **must** be `'\0'`-terminated, only when it is, you have C-String.

Comment: thank you. but I din't understant why you put a zero on `char cs[] = { getc(fl), 0} ` ? shouln't be a `\0`?

Comment: and is probably to do `char cs[] = { c=getc(fl), 0}` because of the c in while loop

Comment: @Ricardo no, it's because of creating a valid c-string. I made an edit of my answer where I address this (and a bit more)

Comment: thank you. I will need a little time to read and understand. thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Array name is not a modifiable lvalue*. You are assigning to it. Violating rules. That's why compiler complained. Even if it was modifiable you are having an incompatibility in type. Assigning a `char` to `char[]`.

More logical would be to do this

```
playerTOP[n].nome[some_index]=c;
```

You have to store those characters in the `nome` member array of the struct.(which is a `char` array not `char`).

Also make `int c` and then do the check `c!=EOF`.

Comment: thanks. you are right, I forgot that. the name is a string not an element.

Answer (score 1):

name is an array of characters and since you are copying character by character, need to use **playTop[n].name[x]=c;** since name is a character pointer doesn't make sense to compiler when you try to assign a character to it.

Answer (score 1):

the whole, bug ridden:

```
while(c!=EOF){
        while(c!=':'){
            c=getc(fl);
            if(c!=':') playTop[n].name=c;
        }
        if(c==':')fscanf(fl, "  %d  %d\n", &playTop[n].numQuest, &playTop[n].wrongs);
```

can be easily reduced (and should be reduced) to the clean:

```
while( 3 == fscanf( fl, " %19[^:]: %d %d", 
      playTop[n].name,   
      &playtop[n].numQuest, 
      &playTop[n].wrongs ) )
{
    n++;
}
```